# NavigationController doesn't update navigation item

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I've just started developing iOS applications. Now I have such problem. 
I have NavigationController with TestController class set as root and second controller (class SecondController). I try to redirect TestController to SecondController in method viewDidLoad of TestController with help of method setViewControllers of my NavigationController. Second controller is instantiated and shown successfully, but NavigationController keeps the old navigation item's title that TestController had.
I've uploaded test project to cloud: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/D2AC/GBTUboBSo. Screen with green background and title "abacaba" must be shown, but instead of that title "Controller 1" of TestController is shown.

In real project, i want to use such structure for login screen (check if user is logged in viewdidLoad and if not, redirect him to login screen).

Can you help me, what can be a problem?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "I try to redirect TestController to SecondController in method viewDidLoad of TestController with help of method setViewControllers of my NavigationController?"

Comment: @jefflovejapan, I want to call setViewControllers method of UiNavigationController to replace the initial controller (TestController instance) with new controller (SecondController instance). Navigation stack must be cleared and user shouldn't have a possibility to return to previous controller.

Comment: So inside the body of `TestController.viewDidLoad` you have a line like `navigationController?.viewControllers  = [SecondController()]`?

Comment: @jefflovejapan, `navigationController?.setViewControllers([nextController!], animated: false)`


please see the example project i've attached to question.

Comment: Are you setting `SecondController.title`?

Comment: yes, i set title of new controller. In two places (viewDidLoad of secondcontroller and before setViewControllers in Testcontroller).

Comment: Are you setting the title on the view controller or on its navigation item?

Comment: @jefflovejapan, on its navigation item.

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Serega you should use this code to redirect to next screen

```
     let nextController = 
     storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NextController")
     nextController?.navigationItem.title = "abacaba"
     navigationController?.pushViewController(nextController!, animated: true)
```

> And i will look like this

[image]

Comment: Hello!
But I don't want to push, i want to replace the TestController with SecondController. Navigation stack must be cleared and user shouldn't have a possibility to return to previous controller.

Comment: Ok let me try it